# Allow only numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

I used this script

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
  {
    var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;                        
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 47 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
    if (e.shiftKey) return false;
    return true;
 }
```

But this script not working in firefox alone.
Any alternatives to restrict user for shift key in javascript?

Comment: Did you actually use `.shiftkey`? If yes: It needs to be `.shiftKey` with an uppercase `K`

Comment: I used both with uppercase and lowercase. Not working in Firefox. It allows.

Comment: It would help if you say _what_ you're trying to accomplish by "restricting" the shift key. Do you want to block any keypress while the shift key is down? Do you want the shift key to have no effect (e.g. `shift+a` to produce `a` instead of `A`)?

Comment: @itzArun: Then you need to show more code. For example, the binding of the event handler. Maybe you are using the wrong one.

Comment: I've updated my script. I want to allow only numbers in my textbox field

Comment: See [HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](http://stackoverflow.com/a/469419/298479)

Comment: @ThiefMaster, What about disabling the shiftkey? I dont think this question is functionally duplicated with the one you linked.

Comment: @Starx: According to his comment "I want to allow only numbers in my textbox field" that's what he actually wants to achieve.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, I understand the reason, why you did so. But the original question was to block `shift` key which was a different case IMO. Although, what he wanted was totally different from what he needed.

Comment: **USE REGULAR EXPRESSIONS AND NOT KEYCODES, DIFFERENT KEYBOARDS AND ANY BROWSERS ANSWER DIFFERENT RESPONSE. EXAMPLE THAT WORK IN DIFFERENT BROWSERS...** http://jsfiddle.net/rogeriodemoraes/pkaq2kng/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event` is not defined in Firefox, it's breaking your code. Put it after testing for `evt`:

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
  {
    var e = evt || window.event; //window.event is safer, thanks @ThiefMaster
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;                        
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 47 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
    if (e.shiftKey) return false;
    return true;
 }
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/ZabPy/1/)

Check your error console next time. :)

Comment: Another option would be using `window.event` which is `undefined` but accessing it won't throw an error.

Comment: Nice suggestion, edited answer to include the other possible fix with given credit.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code..**

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

check the fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/kabichill/8FgH4/

Comment: check the fiddle ..http://jsfiddle.net/kabichill/8FgH4/

Answer (score -2):

U can restrict any key press (a group of them also) by using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $('#PHONE_NUMBER').keypress(function(e) {
            var a = [];
            var k = e.which;

            for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
            a.push(i);
            a.push(8);
            if (!(a.indexOf(k)>=0))
                e.preventDefault();
            });
});
```

Where #phone number is the id of the input element and the for loop and push function pushes only allowed characters.
48 to 58 is key values for digits 0-9 on key board

Comment: Jquery is not the magical answer for everything. Stop using jquery for things that simple javescript can solve.

Comment: Using jQuery is fine, but creating an array on every key press?!

Comment: @Truth [jQuery is awesome and do all things!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif)

Comment: @ThiefMaster  Congrats on the diamond